# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un arreglo en un text-area y guardarlo en una variable?

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando con Angular, y se me ocurrió que podría ser sencillamente con una interpolación (dobles llaves), pero no funciona en este caso. Quiero que en un `text-area` se muestre el siguiente arreglo:

```
public json: any = {
      "cotizacion": {
        "paq": 0,
        "col": "",
        "estado": 0,
        "mod": 0,
        "valor": 0,
        "cp": "",
        "forpag": "",
        "edad": 0,
        "mcpio": 0,
        "uso": "",
        "password": "",
      }
     }
```

Mi código de **HTML** está así

```
  <div class="row h-40">
    <textarea class="w-100 h-100">{{json[0].cotizacion}}</textarea>
  </div>
```

También lo intenté con `[innerHTML]` pero el resultado fue el mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El objeto json no es un arreglo por eso no puedes acceder a sus elementos por su índice [0]. Tienes que hacerlo llamando el nombre de la propiedad como `json.cotizacion`. Y usar un pipe para motrarlo como texto:

```
<div class="row h-40">
    <textarea class="w-100 h-100">{{json.cotizacion | json}}</textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿Y en caso de que fuera un JSON?

Comment: No comprendo tu pregunta